# CQ5: How can I propagate a logged-in user's security context to an integrated web application?

Tags: java, security, aem

Given is the following:

- an AEM CMS which allows login of users
- a Java web application (built with Spring) that is integrated into the AEM CMS via URL.

Question: Once the user is logged-in, how can the CMS propagate the user's identity (with proof of his authentication) reliably to the integrated web application?

Answer (score 0):

Its really the question of what you want to share as authentication to web-service. Your question doesn't specify what kind of web-service call it is?

Once user is logged in then you can get the username from below code. It will give you `anonymous` if user is not logged-in.

Using this information you can make a call to web-service conditionally. And it also depends on what kind of hand-shake is happening b/w AEM and Spring web-service.

```
com.adobe.granite.security.user.UserProperties
UserProperties userProfile = slingRequest.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(UserProperties.class);
            if(null != userProfile){
                UserName = userProfile.getAuthorizableID();
            }
```